# COUNT + GROUP_CONCAT with GROUP BY returns wrong values

Tags: mysql, sql

The query below aims to return a list of events containing event names, COUNT of users assigned to event, COUNT of comments left and a GROUP_CONCAT of names of the users assigned to event.

It all works OK if I LEFT JOIN either on the comments or assignments tables but not on both!

If I join on both all counts multiply with each other. If one event has 3 comments and 5 users assigned the comment count and the user count will be 5 x 3 = 15. Also the GROUP_CONCAT will return each user name 3 times like: `Joe, Joe, Joe, Mike, Mike, Mike,...` instead of `Joe, Mike,...`

I wish someone would explain why. And post a solution :)

```
SELECT 
    e.id_eve,
    e.title_eve,
    v.name_ven,
    COUNT(a.ideve_ass) AS count_ass,
    COUNT(c.ideve_com) AS count_com,
    GROUP_CONCAT(u.firstname_usr) AS users_eve
FROM 
    rsevents_eve AS e
    LEFT JOIN venues_ven v ON e.idven_eve = v.id_ven
    LEFT JOIN rscomments_com c ON c.ideve_com = e.id_eve
    LEFT JOIN rsassignments_ass a ON a.ideve_ass = e.id_eve
    LEFT JOIN users_usr u ON u.id_usr = a.idusr_ass
GROUP BY 
    e.id_eve
```

Comment: do distinct like `GROUP_CONCAT(distinct u.firstname_usr) AS users_eve`?

Comment: DISTINCT on COUNT and GROUP_CONCAT works but ONLY if the key the counts are are the primary keys. If the count is done on the foreign keys (as in my query) the distinct counts return 1. Why?

Comment: it might be because some foreign key values that you have are null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are aggregating along different dimensions, so you are getting a Cartesian product for each event.

There are several solutions.  One is to pre-aggregate each table.  I'm going to suggest an alternative, correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT e.id_eve, e.title_eve, v.name_ven,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM rsassignments_ass a 
        WHERE a.ideve_ass = e.id_eve
       ) as count_ass,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM rscomments_com c 
        WHERE c.ideve_com = e.id_eve
       ) as count_com,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(u.firstname_usr)
        FROM users_usr u JOIN
             rsassignments_ass a 
             ON u.id_usr = a.idusr_ass
        WHERE a.ideve_ass = e.id_eve
       ) as users_eve
FROM rsevents_eve e LEFT JOIN
     venues_ven v
     ON e.idven_eve = v.id_ven;
```

A third way to fix this is to put `DISTINCT` in each `COUNT()` and `GROUP_CONCAT()`.  However, the above should be the most efficient method if you have indexes on the `JOIN` keys.

Comment: The funny thing is that the DISTINCT option only works if the COUNT is done on the primary key of the table, not on the foreign key (as I did), in which case it returns just 1. Why?

Comment: Can you say which option has better performance, DISTINCT or the correlated sub-queries considering that tables are all indexed as they should?

Comment: @lavirius . . . You should try both versions on your data and see which works better.